# Filter an array of objects returns empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I hae the following array of objects:

```
arr = [
    {
        name: "john",
        age: 24,
        gender: "male"
    },
    {
        name: "jane",
        age: 27,
        gender: "female"
    },
    {
        name: "joe",
        age: 29,
        gender: "male"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to filter the `name` and `age` property into a new array. I tried this:

```
const newFields = arr.filter((item) => {
    return (
        item.name && item.age
    );
});
```

But for some reason `newFields` returns an empty array.

Comment: change `filter` to `map` and return `{name: item.name, age:item.age}`

Comment: it works absolutely fine. Maybe in between array filtering and array definition you mutate the array and array is already empty?

Comment: `filter` use it to *remove* entries from an array. `map` use it to *transform* entries from an array. You want the latter.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a one liner too with the arrow function and  [Parameter Context Matching](http://es6-features.org/#ParameterContextMatching)

`const newFields = arr.map(({ name, age }) => ({ name, age }));`

Your solution's result can not be empty but the original array, because in this case the return value of your `filter` function will be always true (every item has the name and age property) which doesn't filter anything from the original `arr` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "john",
    age: 24,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "jane",
    age: 27,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "joe",
    age: 29,
    gender: "male"
  }
];

const newFields = arr.map(item => {
  return {
      name: item.name,
      age: item.age
    }
});
console.log(newFields)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new array with a subset of the original - then you can iterate over the array and push the desired elements into its own array.

That said if all you are trying to get is the name and age of the existing array - why do you need to create a separate array? - you can just iterate over the original array and reference only the desired values from each item.

```js
let arr = [
    {
        name: "john",
        age: 24,
        gender: "male"
    },
    {
        name: "jane",
        age: 27,
        gender: "female"
    },
    {
        name: "joe",
        age: 29,
        gender: "male"
    }
]

let newArr = [];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    newArr.push({name:item.name, age:item.age})
});

console.log(newArr); // gives [{"name": "john","age": 24},{"name": "jane","age": 27},{"name": "joe","age": 29}]
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering performance-wise how good forEach is compared to, say map?